# can not add dependency mapBox SDK error fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, androidx

problem add mapBoxSDK android

gradle class path this :

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

and libs :

```
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'

  implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.8.1'
```

error this :

```
Failed to resolve: fragment
Open File


Failed to resolve: core
Open File
```

**UPDATE**

gradle app file :

use **androidx** & **java 1.8** & **gradle 2.3.1**

I guess I do not support Androidx?
Do you think this is a problem?
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
       ....
    }
   ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.1.0-alpha01"
    def room_version = "2.0.0-rc01"
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    // lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.0.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.8.1'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.26.0'


}
```

Comment: Can you please show your complete gradle files.

Comment: https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/navigation/overview follow this link

Comment: @suresh-madaparthi thanks , unfortunately, it does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added the following dependencies and my problem has been resolved

i'm **remove** :

```
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

and **added** this :

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
kapt 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding your dependencies to the project level gradle file. Class path addresses should go in the project level buid.gradle file whilst library dependencies should go into the app level build.gradle files.

In your app level build.gradle you should add:

```
dependencies {
...
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
   implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.8.1'
}
```

And in your project level you should add:

```
dependencies {
...
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in your Project->build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help

Comment: Maybe its cause by other dependencies. try commenting mapbox sdk